# Uncheck all child if parent checkbox is unchecked

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am creating a page with multiple checkboxes. Some checkboxes are nested and other are not. If a particular checkbox is checked it will display more boxes under it with options to select. If unchecked it will hide the child boxes. Right now this is being done with CSS only. If I check the parent to show the child I do not want the child boxes to be checked. I go through and check the boxes I need and then I would submit the values from any checked boxes including values in the parent boxes. All of this works fine. What need to happen is if any of the parents are unchecked then the children are unchecked. Below is the code I have.

```css
input {
 position: absolute;
 left: -9999px;
}

label {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 30px 15px 15px;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #6a8494;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  white-space: nowrap;
  user-select: none;
  transition: background-color .2s, box-shadow .2s;
  width: 300px;
}

label::before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 32px;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 100px;
  transition: background-color .2s;
}

label:hover, input:focus + label {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}

input:checked + label {
  background-color: #ab576c;
}

input:checked + label::before {
  background-color: #fff;
}

div {
  display: none;
  appearance: none;
  margin: 40px auto 0;
  padding: 5px 40px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  background-color: #9ab593;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#permitted:checked ~ #bodyparts {
  display: block;
}

#neck:checked ~ #direction {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<section>
 <input id="permitted" type="checkbox">
 <label for="permitted" class="side-label">Click to show more options</label>
 <div id="bodyparts">
  <input id="head" type="checkbox">
  <label for="head">head</label>
  
  <input id="neck" type="checkbox">
  <label for="neck">neck (click for more options)</label>
  
  <div id="direction">
   <input id="left" type="checkbox">
   <label for="left">left</label>
   
   <input id="right" type="checkbox">
   <label for="right">right</label>
   
   <input id="both" type="checkbox">
   <label for="both">both</label>
  </div>
  
  <input id="middle-back" type="checkbox">
  <label for="middle-back">middle back</label>
  
  <input id="lower-back" type="checkbox">
  <label for="lower-back">lower back</label>
 </div>
</section>
```

Right now if I "uncheck" the first option it hides the other options, but they are still "checked" even though they are hidden.

Comment: You will have to resort to Javascript to achieve that.

Comment: You can write CSS to adjust the colors on uncheck of the parent however that will not change the checked state, thus when the parent is checked the child will again appear with the checked color as it is still checked. You will need to use JavaScript to do this.

Comment: As commented, css is not the way to solve it. You need a bit of JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've tagged this with jQuery, it's pretty easy. Add a class to the "additional info" section and we can use this as an easy hook as a sibling of the original checkbox.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", function(){
    //if the checkbox has a sibling qwith the additional-info class
    if($(this).siblings(".additional-info").length > 0){
      //if the checkbox is uncheckd
      if(!$(this).is(":checked")){
        //uncehck the checkbox
        $(this).siblings(".additional-info").find("[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", false);
      }
    }
})
});
```

```css
input {
 position: absolute;
 left: -9999px;
}

label {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 30px 15px 15px;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #6a8494;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  white-space: nowrap;
  user-select: none;
  transition: background-color .2s, box-shadow .2s;
  width: 300px;
}

label::before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 32px;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 100px;
  transition: background-color .2s;
}

label:hover, input:focus + label {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}

input:checked + label {
  background-color: #ab576c;
}

input:checked + label::before {
  background-color: #fff;
}

div {
  display: none;
  appearance: none;
  margin: 40px auto 0;
  padding: 5px 40px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  background-color: #9ab593;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#permitted:checked ~ #bodyparts {
  display: block;
}

#neck:checked ~ #direction {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
 <input id="permitted" type="checkbox">
 <label for="permitted" class="side-label">Click to show more options</label>
 <div id="bodyparts">
  <input id="head" type="checkbox">
  <label for="head">head</label>
  
  <input id="neck" type="checkbox">
  <label for="neck">neck (click for more options)</label>
  
  <div id="direction" class="additional-info">
   <input id="left" type="checkbox">
   <label for="left">left</label>
   
   <input id="right" type="checkbox">
   <label for="right">right</label>
   
   <input id="both" type="checkbox">
   <label for="both">both</label>
  </div>
  
  <input id="middle-back" type="checkbox">
  <label for="middle-back">middle back</label>
  
  <input id="lower-back" type="checkbox">
  <label for="lower-back">lower back</label>
 </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

I will just show how to achieve that for one part to show what to do.

Since you have no clear parent-child structure, you will have to work on the elements referencing them by their `id` attributes directly:

```js
neck.addEventListener('change', () => {
  if (neck.checked) [left, right, both].forEach(el => el.checked = false);
})
```

```css
input {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

label {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 30px 15px 15px;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #6a8494;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  white-space: nowrap;
  user-select: none;
  transition: background-color .2s, box-shadow .2s;
  width: 300px;
}

label::before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 32px;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 100px;
  transition: background-color .2s;
}

label:hover,
input:focus+label {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}

input:checked+label {
  background-color: #ab576c;
}

input:checked+label::before {
  background-color: #fff;
}

div {
  display: none;
  appearance: none;
  margin: 40px auto 0;
  padding: 5px 40px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  background-color: #9ab593;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#permitted:checked~#bodyparts {
  display: block;
}

#neck:checked~#direction {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <input id="permitted" type="checkbox">
  <label for="permitted" class="side-label">Click to show more options</label>
  <div id="bodyparts">
    <input id="head" type="checkbox">
    <label for="head">head</label>

    <input id="neck" type="checkbox">
    <label for="neck">neck (click for more options)</label>

    <div id="direction">
      <input id="left" type="checkbox">
      <label for="left">left</label>

      <input id="right" type="checkbox">
      <label for="right">right</label>

      <input id="both" type="checkbox">
      <label for="both">both</label>
    </div>

    <input id="middle-back" type="checkbox">
    <label for="middle-back">middle back</label>

    <input id="lower-back" type="checkbox">
    <label for="lower-back">lower back</label>
  </div>
</section>
```